# What is default of repository in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to use maven to build projects, and IDE I am using is eclipse. For projects I built before, I never used attributes `<repository>` in POM file and they are running very well.

But when I read some projects in github, they always come with a POM file containing quite a lot of `<repository>`. After reading maven official website, I know that `<repositories>` are location to download jar files, but I am able to import all classes only specifying `<dependencies>` not `<repositories>`.

My question is why can I download libs without specify `<repositories>`? Is there a default value for repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/), which is automatically bundled with your pom.xml / settings.xml if you don't specify one.

You usually specify a repo in your pom.xml when you need to access an artifact that your company produces internally, or when you want to reference snapshots or the third-party company you're working with hasn't given their artifacts to Central.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me what SANPSHOT means in maven? Is it a testing version?

Comment: It is a version you're working on, or more formally a version that has not been released.